# Using ANTLR with Eclipse and ANTLR IDE: cannot add ANTLR jar 'Invalid ANTLR home Reason: Couldn't create package'

Tags: eclipse, antlr, antlrv3ide

I'm trying to use ANTLR with Eclipse (ANTLR version 3.5, Eclipse Juno), wing the ANTLR IDE plugin, following the setup steps here: http://vimeo.com/8001326
However, when it comes to adding the ANTLR package, I get an error 'Invalid ANTLR home Reason: Coulnd't create package'. Clicking details gives: 'Couldn't create a package
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:bin\java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified'
I also tried this page but it was no help: http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/doc/gettingstarted/basictutorial/definingapackage.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you manage to install ANTLR IDE plugin into Juno?

Comment: I think you have found the crux of the problem. I've managed to get it working with Indigo. I think I mistakenly installed the Indigo version. Thanks a lot.